# Can duplicate primary keys be apparent for READ COMMITTED isolation?

Tags: sql, isolation-level

I have a table with a primary key, which is backed by a uniqueness constraint. A query with SERIALIZABLE isolation should therefore never return two rows with the same primary key. But is that also true for a query with READ COMMITTED isolation? What is the most lax isolation level for which apparent duplicate primary keys are impossible?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the most lax isolation level for which apparent duplicate
>   primary keys are impossible?

`REPEATABLE READ` or `READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT`

In SQL Server it is definitely possible for a scan at `READ COMMITTED` (locking)  to read a row twice.

At this isolation level the row locks are released as soon as the data is read, not at the end of the statement or transaction.

Thus it is possible for a scan reading an index in key order to encounter the same row again if the key was updated after the initial read moving it until later in the index. In order to observe the duplicate primary key in practice the index being scanned would likely need to be on a different key column than the PK itself.

`REPEATABLE READ` can miss rows if data that has yet to be read moves forward in the index to a part already scanned but this wouldn't allow the phenomena of apparent duplicate primary keys to occur.

Answer (score 0):

On OracleDB, as far as you PK isn't deferrable and deferred, you could not violate it: even in lowest supported 'READ COMMITTED' level (ANSI/ISO Level 1), different sessions operating on same rows occour into a row-lock contention. So, the second session's DML will stay in wait until the first release the lock - by committing or rollbacking - then it's validated on the fly and it would fail if the PK is violated.

Comment: To be clear you can't actually violate it in SQL Server either. The question is about *apparent* violations. e.g. where a `SELECT * FROM T` returns the same PK value multiple times as the result even though the table itself has no duplicates.

Comment: On OracleDB cursors are frozen when opened, so no way to read a duplicated PK, no matter what isolation level you set, unless PK are deferred and the violation is due to uncommited data on the same session.